# Stop click event in 500ms, how i can do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i created memory game with js and jQuery and i have one small problem , because right now someone can display more then 2 hidden elements before they hide again.

```
if(arr1[0] === arr1[1]){
        score += 10;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $board.find('[data-id="'+arr1[0]+'"]').remove()
            arr1 = [];
            scoreHTML.text(score)
        },500)
    } else if (arr1.length === 2 && arr1[0] !== arr1[1]) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.box').data('data-id', arr1[0]).fadeIn();
            $('.box').data('data-id', arr1[1]).fadeIn();
            arr1 = [];
        },500)
    }
```

Anyone have idea how i can block click event on this Timeout ?

Comment: Please show all the relevant code (HTML and CSS too) in a "code snippet" in your question so that we can have a running version of your code.

Comment: Assign a `running` variable to your setTimeout in your else block. Then check if that timeout is active before revealing the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you clear the timeout when you don't want it to be executed ?

```
clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
if (someCondition) {
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        // Do something
    },500);
} else {
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        // Do something else
    },500);
}
```

(I used this.timeoutId assuming the code is embedded in a class but otherwize you could still use a variable)

I'm not sure i get your question right, but hope this helps.